# AngularJS: Radio button not getting selected as per ngModel, using with ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

Radio button does not get checked by default based on the model value.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ($scope) => {
  $scope.decideVote ={
    vote: {
     yes: "Yes",
      no: "No",
     maybe: "Maybe"
   //if i have more values here, i will get more radio buttons 
    } 
  }
  
   //uncomment for testing. 
   $scope.serverVoted= {
   vote: {yes:"Yes"}
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <form name="myForm">
  <p>Select Vote</p>
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="i in decideVote.vote">
    <label>
            {{i}}
     <input type="radio"  name="same"
                    ng-model="serverVoted.vote" ng-value="i" />
    </label>  
   </li>
  </ul>
 </form>
 <div>
```

As mentioned in angularjs docs , the radio should get checked automatically based on the model value. I will paste working sample here but the real scenario is like this.

Component defined as radioButtonsFromJsonObj , there can be many elements as radioButtonsFromJsonObj and might be using different Json object to populate radio button but the model is same for a particular group of radio buttons.

But when i open the page again and model have the right values still the radio buttons are not getting checked as per model.

Also the actual scenario is like a component generating the template and in that the binding is passed for get the ngModel dynamically for each elements.The ngModel gets set properly but when try to reopen and read data from server it does not get checked automatically. So tried to create same scenario above.
Inside component have init block and constructor block,just creating a $ctrl variable.

the binding is as followed

```
bindings: {
  model: '=ngModel'
}
```

in template have ngRepeat and inside each iteration generating template like this.

```
 <input type="radio"  name="same"  ng-model="$ctrl.model" ng-value="i" />
```

and the main html can have many elements.

```
<radioButtonsFromJsonObj ng-model="request.Voting1"> </radioButtonsFromJsonObj >
<radioButtonsFromJsonObj ng-model="request.Voting2"> </radioButtonsFromJsonObj >
```

Answer (score 0):

serverVoted.vote is object so replace with this ng-model="serverVoted.vote.yes"

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ($scope) => {
  $scope.decideVote ={
    vote: {
     yes: "Yes",
      no: "No",
     maybe: "Maybe"
   //if i have more values here, i will get more radio buttons 
    } 
  }
  
   //uncomment for testing. 
   $scope.serverVoted= {
   vote: {yes:"Yes"}
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <form name="myForm">
  <p>Select Vote</p>
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="i in decideVote.vote">
    <label>
            {{i}}
     <input type="radio"  name="same"  ng-model="serverVoted.vote.yes" ng-value="i" />
    </label>  
   </li>
  </ul>
 </form>
 <div>
```

Comment: I don't want to send a string to my model, the complete object and selected property which would be like this in my model ng-model="request.serverVoted.vote: {yes:"Yes"} " thats why am using i in options

Answer (score 0):

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> $scope.serverVoted= {
>    vote: {yes:"Yes"}
> }
> ```

Instead:

```
 $scope.server = { vote: "Yes" };
```

The DEMO

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ($scope) => {
  $scope.decideVote ={
    vote: {
     yes: "Yes",
      no: "No",
     maybe: "Maybe"
   //if i have more values here, i will get more radio buttons 
    } 
  }
  
   //uncomment for testing. 
   $scope.serverVoted= {vote: "Yes"};
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <form name="myForm">
  <p>Select Vote</p>
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="i in decideVote.vote">
    <label>
            {{i}}
     <input type="radio"  name="same"
                    ng-model="serverVoted.vote" ng-value="i" />
    </label>  
   </li>
  </ul>
 </form>
 <div>
```

Comment: Sir, I will try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @georgeawg : `ng-value ="i"` means the object is getting stored with ` "yes": "Yes"` , That means the model serverVoted.vote will have  vote: {"yes": "Yes"} why can't the model select the radio buttons based on this value? why do we have to give it one single property? like the way you gave is still a string isn't it?